# How to run a script outside of home directory via cron

Tags: cron

I have a script located at `/home/user/backup.sh`

I'm trying to execute this script via my root crontab. It isn't running. The script works if I create the crontab under my `user` account.

Is there anyway to run this script as the root crontab? Here is the line I am using.

`25 20 * * * sh /home/user/backup.sh`

---

Contents of script:

```
tar -czvf /home/user/backup/backup.tar.gz /var/www/
mysqldump -u root -p password --all-databases > /home/user/backup/backup.sql
rsync -avz /home/user/backup user@myserver:/home/user/
```

Comment: Could it be caused by some permission or system level protection such as selinux?  Check the output of `sestatus`.

Comment: Is your script perhaps dependent on what directory it is run from, or dependent on environment variables?

Comment: It's a backup script that creates a tarball and then rsyncs it to a remote VPS. I use absolute paths always. Very basic

Comment: Hmmm.  Do you specify the absolute path where the tarball is to be created?  (Default is to create in `$PWD`, I believe; not sure where `cron` runs out of.)  From what you describe above I see no reason the cronjob should fail.  Does `sudo sh /home/user/backup.sh` work?

Comment: update your question with content of script. monitor your `/var/log/cron` or `/var/log/syslog` to see if anything from crond. output your cron like `1 2 * * *  /path/to/your/script &>/tmp/script.log`. do  you have `$PATH` set in crontab file?

Comment: Updated with contents of script

Comment: your `root` account has key added on remote server?

Comment: yes, I created ssh keys that are in working order

Comment: But you're trying to do the ssh as `user` instead of as `root`.  What if you try `sudo -u user rsync ...` instead?

Comment: You're right...its hanging up at the password because it's trying to ssh as the root account and root doesn't have the keys. If you want to write this up as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root` has full access on *your* system, but doesn't necessarily have all the keys to other systems that your normal user account has.

So the trouble is:

```
rsync -avz /home/user/backup user@myserver:/home/user/
                             ^^^^
```

If you cause `root` to execute this command as *you*, your keys will be used and the command will be successful:

```
sudo -u user rsync -avz /home/user/backup user@myserver:/home/user/
```

Alternatively, you could install `root`'s public key as an accepted SSH key for `user` on the `myserver` system.